# java adt make new project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i'm trying to setup a second project in eclipse adt. Each time I do, another appcompat_v7 folder is created. I selecte new > android application project > enter app name > create custom launcher icons > finally set fullscreen activity. Once the project is setup i get an error "the container 'android dependencies' references non existing library '\appcompat_v7_8\bin\appcompat_v_8.jar'". How do I correct this issue and setup a second app project? Thank you for the help, i'm just beginning.

Comment: what's your max version ..

Comment: right now the largest version is appcompat_v7_8